# How to render fields in flask admin dynamically

Tags: flask-wtforms, flask-admin

How could I manage displayable fields on selected Module type?

My goal is: When module type 'Post' selected I want to display 'Title' and 'Description' fields. When I choose different type - I want to render only 'Title' field

What method of forms should I use for that behavior?
[image: ModelView]

```py
class DailyRoutineTaskPackageView(ModelView):
    can_create = True
    can_edit = True
    can_delete = True
    page_size = 20

    create_template = "daily_routine_task_create.html"
    edit_template = "daily_routine_task_edit.html"

    form_columns = (
        "name",
        "active",
        "community",
        "datetime_start",
        "datetime_end",
    )

    form_ajax_refs = {
        "lgf_uuid": lifegraph_function_loader,
    }
    form_args = dict(
        community=dict(validators=[DataRequired()]),
    )

    inline_models = (DailyRoutineTaskInlineView(DailyRoutineTask),)
```

```py
class DailyRoutineTaskInlineView(InlineFormAdmin):
    form_columns = ("id", "sequence_number", "routine_type", "routine_id", "custom_title", "custom_description", "lgf_uuid")

    # TODO: validate sequence

    form_overrides = dict(
        routine_type=SelectField,
        routine_id=NonValidatingSelectField,
        lgf_uuid=CompassAjaxSelectField,
        custom_title=TextField,
        custom_description=TextField,
    )

    form_extra_fields = {
        "sequence_number": IntegerField("Sequence Number", [validators.DataRequired()]),
        "lgf_uuid": lifegraph_function_loader.field_type(
            loader=lifegraph_function_loader,
            label="LifeGraph Function",
            allow_blank=True,
        ),
        "custom_title": TextField("Title"),
    }
    # based on some conditions
    form_extra_fields["custom_description"] = TextField("Description")
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it with this ugly thing on frontend side by manipulating template HTML

```js
  function getSelectedTasksArray() {
    // form array like ['service', 'article', 'post']
    return $('select[id$=-routine_type]').map(function () {
      return this.value
    }).get();
  };

  function updateAllTasks(selected_tasks_array) {
    selected_tasks_array.forEach(function (item, index) {
      let input_id = "input[id=tasks-".concat(index, "-custom_description]");
      if (item != "service") {
        $(input_id).val(null);
        $(input_id).parent().parent().parent().hide();  // hide description fields 
      } else {
        $(input_id).parent().parent().parent().show();  // show description fields 
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use js with edit_template and jinja2.